# Acces to a member of the structure

Tags: c, struct, bmp

I have the next Structures:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct Pix
{
    uint16_t R, G, B;
    int32_t BW;
}Pix;
#pragma pack(pop)

//Estructura del header del bmp:
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct BitMap
{
    int16_t Signature;          //Tipo de archivo (BM)          
    int32_t Reserved1;          //reservado, debe ser cero
    int32_t Reserved2;          //reservado, debe ser cero
    int32_t DataOffSet;         //Offset de los datos de los pixeles

    int32_t Size;               //Tamaño del resto del header
    int32_t Width;              //Ancho del bmp en pixeles
    int32_t Height;             //Alto del bmp en pixeles
    int16_t Planes;             //Numero de planos -> seteado en 1
    int16_t BitsPerPixel;       //Número de bits por pixel
    int32_t Compression;            //Tipo de compresion, usualmente 0
    int32_t SizeImage;          //Tamaño en bytes del bitmap    
    int32_t XPixelsPreMeter;        //Pixeles horizontales por metro
    int32_t YPixelsPreMeter;        //Pixeles verticales por metro
    int32_t ColorsUsed;         //Número de colores usados
    int32_t ColorsImportant;        //Número de colores "importantes"
    struct Pix *pixels;         //Declara estructura Pix tipo *pixels
}BitMap;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I do not know how to access a specific value of the structure "Pix" by means of the "BitMap" structure, where a pointer to the structure Pix is used.
I need to access a specific data from the Pix structure, not a memory address.

Comment: `bitmap.pixels[i].R`.

Comment: It looks like `pixels` is a pointer to a blob that represents a 2 dimensional image. You need to determine which pixel you want to access first. Then figure out how to calculate the linear offset from `pixel` based on the 2 dimensional coordinates. Probably something like `i = x * bitmap.Width + y`. Then, you can do as @EugeneSh. said.

Comment: @jxh the bitmap stride needs to be considered, not its width (although they may be the same).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, which is why I said "probably". Also, it is why it is not an answer.

Comment: In 24-bit or 32-bit image, you have one byte for each of these colors: red, green, blue. Each of these colors is from 0 to 256, it's one byte or `uint8_t`. Each pixel has 3 colors, or 3 colors + alpha channel for 32-bit image. I don't know why you have 3 * `uint16_t` plus `uint32_t`, that makes it 10 bytes or 80 bits per pixel. The 2nd and 3rd structure members are not exactly right. Your source material is wrong or is doing something odd which is not obvious.